# Queue of students built from double LL

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I'm working on a project where I have to pop 3 students a day from a Queue. My popFront function seems to work perfectly -- as it prints out the correct students, but then my program crashes. Anyone have any idea if there is something in my function that could be making my program crash?

```
void pop_front()
{
    int num = 0;

    if (front == NULL){
        cout<<"No students to pop "<<endl;
        return;
    }


        string value;
        while(num<3)
        {
            Node *temp = front;
            if(front->next)
            {   value = front->name;
                front = front->next;
                front->prev = NULL;
                size--;
                delete temp;
                cout<<value<<" ";
                num++;
                continue;
            }
            value=front->name;
            front = NULL;
            back = NULL;
            delete temp;
            cout<<" Last student in Priority1 list is:  "<<value;
            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: What is back and why it's updated only when poping last student. Does back->next = front? If so then it should also be updated (temp->prev->next = temp->next or sthf like that).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the function that you have written. Your program could have crashed due to the other functions in your code. Check whether you have tried to access illegal memory i.e. memory you have not allocated before anywhere else in your program.